# PhpStorm IDE hints not working on Angular custom Library Components

Tags: angular, phpstorm, angular7

I built a library as explained here:
https://medium.com/@tomsu/how-to-build-a-library-for-angular-apps-4f9b38b0ed11

However, the PhpStorm IDE does not pick the components in the projects where I use this library, e.g. I have a component `my-app-alert`. When I start typing `<my-app` it should autocomplete but it does not. Also, when I write it down completely like `<my-app-alert></my-app-alert>` it shows a warning.

If I load the library module directly from its source, this works great. But if I load it from the `dist/` folder that is created after the library is built, then it does not work. Which means there is something not right in build?

Comment: Can you share how you've structured your PHP project.

Comment: Do you have Angular plugins installed? If not - here's a link to one https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971-angularjs & also please check online docs regarding angular: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/angular.html

Comment: @cgTag there is no php project, its all about Angular

Comment: @Ástþór I dont think it has anything to do with plugins or the IDE itself, because it works when the library is called directly and not in build mode.

Comment: Do you have two projects? One that sources the dist from another? You're not explaining how you've setup your PhpStorm project. So we can't give an answer on how to fix it. You've just told us what isn't working.

Comment: @cgTag yes I have two projects. I mentioned that earlier that I am building a library which is used in another project. The tutorial linked in the main post also explains that. If the library and user app in same project, then it has no advantage in building library.

Answer (score 0):

`dist` is auto-excluded due to [WEB-30918](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30918) for better performance... And completion/type resolving doesn't consider excluded folders:(

You can mark it as "not excluded": from the folder right-click menu, choose **Mark directory as/Not Excluded**. This should help

Comment: The library and its dist is in a different project, and an app in a different project uses it by providing its path in tsconfig.ts, as the tutorials explain.

Comment: this won't work - types resolving is only provided for project files, sources located in different projects are not indexed even when included in tsconfig.json.

Comment: Then how do libraries work? They are in different projects and they are also built and packaged. But they simply do work when included in a user app.

Comment: they do work when included in the app, and don't work otherwise:) To get them work, you have to add them to the project